# Webform mail sender

Tags: webforms

I'm new to Drupal and i'm working on a website that wasn't made by myself.

How can I change the mail sender from  a form made with the webform module?

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the WEBFORM tab and look for the E-mails sub-tab. Fill in an address and click Add.
[image: Configure email]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit by it's edit page, it will be /node/XX/webform/emails where XX is your node number